# Behavior in Form Constructor

Tags: vb.net, forms, picturebox

So, I'm trying to set `.Visible` of a `Button` on true but in the constructor but it wont let me change that variable. Here is a `printscreen` to clarify
[image]

The weird thing is that when I move that bit of code in to the form load event, I don't have that problem. So my question is how is this possible?

EDIT: Visible is true in the designer aswell
EDIT 2: Changed PictureBox to button.

Comment: did you try to modify the properties(modifier) of the of the `picturebox = public`?

Comment: Is a `picturebox`a visible after form was shown?

Comment: @spajce Setting the field public doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely normal.  The Visible property is a bit special, when you read it then it doesn't tell you what value you assigned, it tells you whether the control is actually visible to the user.  Which will never be the case inside the constructor, the control doesn't get visible until the form's Shown event runs.

You don't have a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET page life cycle

> Initialization: During page initialization, controls on the page are
>   available and each control's UniqueID property is set. A master page
>   and themes are also applied to the page if applicable. If the current
>   request is a postback, the postback data has not yet been loaded and
>   control property values have not been restored to the values from view
>   state.
>
> Load During load, if the current request is a postback, control
>   properties are loaded with information recovered from view state and
>   control state.

As you can see the control properties is set during Load, that's why your code works with load event but not in the constructor.

Comment: Its a Windows Forms Application.